# Transfer data from WKInterfaceTable to another WKInterfaceController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I am not familiar with transferring or passing data between two  `WKInterfaceController` in Apple Watch. What I am trying to do is , I have some variable like `name` and `age` in `SecondInterfaceController` so I need to pass some value to them from `WKInterfaceTable` when user tap a row . here is the code :

```
- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex {

    NSString *name;
    NSString *age;

    switch (rowIndex) {
        case 0:
            name = @"Jack";
            age = @"22";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:name forKey:@"kName"];
    [self pushControllerWithName:@"SecondInterfaceController" context:d];

}
```

but I don't know how can I access to the dictionary from SecondIntefaceController and pass it to the _name (WKInterfaceLable) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push your `SecondInterfaceController` it will have `awakeWithContext:` called on it and the `context` parameter will be the dictionary you passed. Then you can pull the name value out of the context dictionary and assign it to your label.

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)context;
    [_name setText:dict[@"kName"]];
}
```

You can pass multiple values by adding multiple keys and values to your dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"kName" : name, @"kAge" : age};
[self pushControllerWithName:@"SecondInterfaceController" context:d];
```

Comment: Thank you ! but what about passing different dictionaries !? I if add   `dinoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:age forKey:@"kAge"];` only one dictionary will be passed , how can I attach multiple value to the one context ?

Comment: @Mc.Lover I added some code to my answer to show how to pass multiple values in the dictionary